# How to find the index of the first row of a matrix that satisfies two conditions in APL Language?

Tags: matrix, lookup, indices, querying, apl

One more question to learn how to use APL Language.
Suppose you have an array, as an example:

| c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 | c5 | c6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 123 | 0 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 3 | 134 | 0 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 3 | 231 | 180 | 1 | 2 | 5 |
| 4 | 121 | 0 | 3 | 2 | 4 |
| 4 | 124 | 120 | 4 | 6 | 3 |
| 4 | 222 | 222 | 5 | 3 | 5 |

So, how to find out which row has a value of 4 in the 1st column and a value grather than 0 in the 3rd column?

The expected answer is 5th line, in the just 5

Comment: Do you want to get the index (`5`) or the row itself (`4 124 120 4 6 3`)? Also, do you want to find the first row or all rows that satisfy the condition?

Comment: Just the index is fine.
The first row only.
Thanks @Bubbler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you want to make such "queries", think *Boolean masks*.

```
      table ← 6 6⍴3 123 0 4 5 6 3 134 0 2 3 4 3 231 180 1 2 5 4 121 0 3 2 4 4 124 120 4 6 3 4 222 222 5
```

Let's extract the first column:

```
      table[;1]
3 3 3 4 4 4
```

And indicate which elements have a value of 4:

```
      table[;1] = 4
0 0 0 1 1 1
```

Similarly, we can indicate which elements of column 3 have value greater than 0:

```
      table[;3] > 0
0 0 1 0 1 1
```

Their intersection (logical AND) indicates all rows that fulfil your criteria:

```
      (table[;1] = 4) ∧ (table[;3] > 0)
0 0 0 0 1 1
```

The index of the first 1 is the row number for the first row that fulfils your criteria:

```
      ((table[;1] = 4) ∧ (table[;3] > 0)) ⍳ 1
5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY0xCgIxEEV7T/HL3ULIzCSLIHoR2SKi2AS0sPECYrOLjWfwAHqiXCT@BGT48P@bGX68pOXhFtP5VMo17tMR@f7EwMnTFwZRg4NHIGEyz6R0nlITyMpBSAKJqHBLTl9TVf0d2r2qNgWmsMjzqzV1XWvdrWXEBr5HfrzxZzZiC9cTTh9IKT8)

Alternatively, we can use the final mask to filter the table and obtain all rows that fulfil your criteria:

```
      ((table[;1] = 4) ∧ (table[;3] > 0)) ⌿ table
4 124 120 4 6 3
4 222 222 5 3 5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///vyQxKSdV4VHbBAUzIHzUu0XBWMHQyFjBQMFEwRQoAuQZmwB5RkCWCRAbGRsqGFoYKBgCRUyBIoZGhkBZoDiQDeKBMEivGVi9kZERGJsCeaZcj/qmgm3S0ADbGm1tGKtgq2CiqfCoY7kCTMw4VsFOwUATKNizXwEs9v8/AA)

Or we can generate all the row numbers:

```
      ⍳ 1 ↑ ⍴ table
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Then use our Boolean mask to filter that, finding the row numbers of all the rows that fulfil your criteria:

```
      ((table[;1] = 4) ∧ (table[;3] > 0)) ⌿ ⍳ 1 ↑ ⍴ table
5 6
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY4xCgJBDEV7T/HL3ULYZGYWQfQissWIYjOghY0XWCxUtPAMHkB77zIXGf8EJHzIf0n4iYc03Zxi2u9KOcZ12iKPd/SsfP3AQdShg0cgoXOeTtl5Sp1AZh2EJJCICqfk7Kurqre97auqKdCFSb49LalpLHU1lwEL@Bb5/MKfuQFLdC3h5ct/3kzK48M@s41Sfg)